# Logging of fatal crashes

Tags: java, logging

How I can make a log of a fatal crash somewhere in my application without using try-cache for the whole program. In my case it is even impossible because I have an RCP application. Where I don't control the start and the end point of it. How I can do the same but only fro one thread? Another question in my application I use Spring how I can send spring logging stream to my log? I use log4j.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be playing with [Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29). But that would work best if you have some control over how the threads are created, or at least a known entry point, so you can set the handler. It also assumes no code in the thread's call stack is catching exceptions and doing something with them.

Otherwise, can't really suggest anything else without knowing more about how the app works.